# How to loop a function to all my buttons in jquery

Tags: jquery, loops

-hello
Someone would be so kind to help me, the truth is not like making these excessive lines of code can be decreased , for example :

I have a button with a function;

```
$( ".btn1" ).click(function() {
    $(".1").show();

    $(".2").hide();
});
```

So much is going well , but I have many buttons with similar functions.

```
$( ".btn2" ).click(function() {
    $(".2").show();

    $(".1").hide();
    $(".3").hide();
    $(".4").hide(); // Etc
});
```

someone to help me please!

Cheers.

----------------MY HTML

```
<section class="menu" id='menus'>

                        <ul>
                            <li class='btn1' >HTML</li>
                            <li class='btn2' >CSS</li>
                            <li class='btn3' >JQUERY</li>
                            <li class='btn4' >JAVA</li>
                            <li class='btn5' >PHP</li>
                            <li class='btn6' >SQL</li>

                        </ul>
 </section>


<div class="contenedor">

                <div class="contenido" >


                    <div class="boxinfo 1" >
                        <div > Example of content 1</div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="boxinfo 2" >
                        <div > Example of content 2</div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="boxinfo 3" >
                        <div > Example of content 3</div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="boxinfo 4" >
                        <div > Example of content 4</div>
                     </div>

                    <div class="boxinfo 5" >
                        <div > Example of content 5</div>
                     </div>

                    <div class="boxinfo 6" >
                        <div > Example of content 6</div>
                     </div>


               </div>
</div>
```

I hope you understand me help

Comment: if the buttons are on the same level try something like this `$('.1').show().siblings().hide();`

Comment: It works if i put each function, but I try to avoid. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    var showAttr = $(this).attr('data-show');
    $('.boxinfo.' + showAttr).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<section class="menu" id='menus'>
    <ul>
        <li class="btn" data-show="1">HTML</li>
        <li class="btn" data-show="2">CSS</li>
        <li class="btn" data-show="3">JQUERY</li>
        <li class="btn" data-show="4">JAVA</li>
        <li class="btn" data-show="5">PHP</li>
        <li class="btn" data-show="6">SQL</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

working example on jsFidle: http://jsfiddle.net/2qyh9q5s/

Answer (score 0):

work with IDs and Classes.
all elements that should be hidden could be hidden with one command if they have all the same class

```
$('.hide-all-this-elements').hide();
```

simple CSS Selector.

work with data Attribtues. this data-attribute has the ID from an element.

```
<button class="btn2" data-show="#elm-2">

<div id="elm-2">

$('.btn2').click(function() { $(  $(this).data('show') ).show() ...
```

[EDIT] replaced a failure